# How to go through each column in dataframe and perform a calculation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, visualization

So I am using plt.subplots() to plot multiple graphs in a single output whilst using matplotlib magic function.

Anyways, I noticed that I was doing the same calculation for each "variable", or column, for my dataframe. Basically, it looks like this

```
%matplotlib inline

fig, (ax1,ax2,ax3) =plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, sharex=False, sharey=True, figsize=(5,5))

#PAPERLESS

ACCOUNT= df.groupby(['PAPERLESS'])['ACCOUNT'].count().rename('ACCOUNT')
cases=df.groupby(['PAPERLESS'])['cases'].sum().rename('cases')
paperless=pd.concat([ACCOUNT,cases],axis=1)
tempdf=paperless
tempdf['percent']=tempdf['cases']/tempdf['ACCOUNT']*100
print(tempdf)
graph1=tempdf['percent'].plot(y='percent',kind='bar', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("Paperless")
graph1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())

plt.tight_layout()
```

So, I am clearly getting the counts of billcounts for each column in my dataframe starting with the variable 'paperless'.
Now, I want to count the accounts for each variable, find the percentage of them out of the number of cases I have, and plot it. How do I automate this using a function or some type of for loop? I have about 15 variables so doing it manually is not really efficient...

Thanks in advance, I will update with what I come up with as this question is open

Comment: You could use something like seaborn's countplot:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html#seaborn.countplot
You would just have to melt your DataFrame using pd.melt, so that each row has one thing that you want to count and one unique id.

Comment: I mean that could work, but I would need a graph for each variable in this case.

Comment: factorplot is your friend
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.factorplot.html#seaborn.factorplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would help you do it

```
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

fig, axes =plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, sharex=False, sharey=True, figsize=(5,5))

aggregators = {'ACCOUNT':'count', 'cases': 'sum'}
variables = ['PAPERLESS', 'More PAPERLESS', 'PAPEERLESS NOT'] #For example
'''
# One way to get all the variables
variables = list(df.columns)
variables.remove('ACCOUNT')
variables.remove('cases')
'''

for variable, ax in zip(variables, axes):
    mid = df.groupby(variable)['ACCOUNT', 'cases'].agg(aggregators) #Map a function to each column
    percts = (mid.ACCOUNT / mid.cases) * 100 #Return a pd.Series with the percentages since you only plot that anyways
    percts.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax) #Only plot percentage
    ax.set_title(variable)
```

Comment: Hmm, the problem is when i run the for loop it points to the mid.df.groupby portion, and has keyerror= 'variable'

Comment: Sorry, just call df.groupby(variable) not string ‘variable’

Comment: Hey looks awesome, I can see exactly where my blocks of code fall in here. Works amazingly.

Comment: Cool, so it sucks because now that i am using variavles= list(df.columns) it only graphs the first three variables... i wonder why it isn't graphing all...and I just accepted it as answer! Thanks :)

Comment: Because of the plt.subplots command, you only enables 3 plots. Increase the number of ncols to be the len of the columns to plot everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(func,axis,addl args)
```

This will apply your function to the elements in a dataframe as specified. I should note that using this method will apply the function twice on the first record for optimization reasons, so if your function appends a list, an iterator, or something else outside of the dataframe you can use:

```
for i in df.index:
    myFunc(df.at[i, column],df.at[i, column2])
```

the reason for that syntax is that you cannot change values in a dataframe using iterrows or the like. You dont want to change something you're iterating over in pandas as a general rule.